# How to get some field in objects?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have a collection "Students".

```
{
    student:"Jone Doe",
    class:"A",
    subjects:
    [
        {subject:"Math",teacher:"Linda","score":"82"},
        {subject:"English",teacher:"Jone","score":"52"},
        {subject:"History",teacher:"Maria","score":"32"},
    ]
}
{
    student:"Baby Doe",
    class:"B",
    subjects:
    [
        {subject:"Math",teacher:"Hilary","score":"52"},
        {subject:"English",teacher:"Notham","score":"52"},
        {subject:"History",teacher:"Hamet","score":"32"},
    ]
}
```

And I want to get all score of Subject "Math" of student.

Im using `aggregation` to get

```
db.collection('studens').aggregate([
      {$match: {"subjects.subject" : "Math" } },
      {$project: {
        _id:0,
         subjects: {
            $filter: {
               input: "$subjects",
               as: "subject",
               cond: { $lte: [ "$$subject.subject", "Math" ] }
            }
         }
      }
   }
]);
```

And the result:

```
{subject:"Math",teacher:"Linda","score":"82"}
{subject:"Math",teacher:"Hilary","score":"52"}
```

But it show all fields, and I want to the result (Only show subject and score):

```
{subject:"Math","score":"82"}
{subject:"Math","score":"52"}
```

How to do this?
Please help me.

Comment: Ok, well I just test your aggregation.. I'm getting: `"result" : [ 
        {
            "subjects" : [ 
               // all values                   
            ]
        }, 
        {
            "subjects" : [ 
                //all values even english and other subject
            ]
        }
    ]` Is this what you are getting?

Comment: change the condition to $eq and now Im getting just Math subject documents..  Is this the output you are looking for ? exclusion of values is not supported, so.. you could probably try with another projection using inclusion of fields

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure how this should be done as exclusion is not supported, I would use another projection for inclusion of the desired fields. ( there's probably a better way of doing this).

Lets try this:

```
db.collection('studens').aggregate([
      {$match: {"subjects.subject" : "Math" } },
      {$project: {
            _id:0,
            subjects: {
                 $filter: {
                    input: '$subjects',
                    as: 'subjects',
                    cond: {$eq: ['$$subjects.subject', 'Math']}
                 }
            }
      }
   },{$project: {subjects: { subject:1, score:1}}}
]);
```

Result:

```
"result" : [ 
    {
        "subjects" : [ 
            {
                "subject" : "Math",
                "score" : "82"
            }
        ]
    }, 
    {
        "subjects" : [ 
            {
                "subject" : "Math",
                "score" : "52"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: thanks for the support, it worked. And the better way for this?

Comment: I can't think of one right this second. If I got a better idea than this, I will edit the answer. I'm glad it helped you.